# Understanding trigger points for vm.dirty_background_ratio and vm.dirty_ratio

Tags: linux

We use prometheus node exporter to monitor our systems

It contains `node_memory_Dirty_bytes`, `node_memory_MemAvailable_bytes`

so is it safe to say that when `node_memory_Dirty_bytes / node_memory_MemAvailable_bytes * 100` exceeds vm.dirty_background_ratio then the background flusher runs?

Similarly when it exeeeds vm.dirty_ratio then all writers block?

Some other documentation said it's more than just available bytes

```
dirty_background_ratio

Contains, as a percentage of total available memory that contains free pages and reclaimable pages, the number of pages at which the background kernel flusher threads will start writing out dirty data.
```

So here it says available = free + reclaimable pages

So does the formula change to

`node_memory_Dirty_bytes / (node_memory_MemFree_bytes + node_memory_KReclaimable_bytes + node_memory_SReclaimable_bytes ) * 100`

Comment: Anyway, i tried plotting both, `node_memory_Dirty_bytes / node_memory_MemAvailable_bytes * 100` doesn't even hit the 10% mark ( we have a 5 second granularity monitoring ) so what's causing the writes? or is the formula wrong? `node_memory_Dirty_bytes / (node_memory_MemFree_bytes + node_memory_KReclaimable_bytes + node_memory_SReclaimable_bytes ) * 100` is outright wrong since it went beyond 100%

Answer (score 0):

How are you observing the "writes"? Dirty pages *may* be written back as a result of a multitude of reasons:

1. The watermarks [`vm.dirty_ratio`](https://docs.kernel.org/admin-guide/sysctl/vm.html#dirty-ratio)/[`dirty_background_ratio`](https://docs.kernel.org/admin-guide/sysctl/vm.html#dirty-background-ratio) (or their `bytes` equivalent) are exceeded, and the kernel starts to either asynchronously or synchronously reclaim memory by flushing dirty pages to disk.
2. Dirty pages are older than [`vm.dirty_writeback_centisecs`](https://docs.kernel.org/admin-guide/sysctl/vm.html#dirty-writeback-centisecs), which also be written back by background flusher threads. This prevents dirty pages from not being persisted to the disk for too long, otherwise a power failure may result in massive data loss.
3. The pages themselves are `fsync()`ed by a syscall, which is an on-demand, synchronous writeback.

The 10% watermark not being hit may be considered a good thing, because the rate of I/O is healthy and not being bottlenecked by the disk.

**References**

- https://docs.kernel.org/admin-guide/sysctl/vm.html
- https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/linux-device-drivers/9781785280009/457ca621-7f40-431f-b8f4-2a9ae03201de.xhtml